# Visual Studio Code deleted files after crash

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has crashed and deleted all files and all file changes I've been working on for the last 5 days, although I've saved them. Is there any solution for recovery ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, your Visual Studio code files can be found at `%appdata%/Code/Backups`

If you are using MacOS, then you can find all your Visual Studio code files at
`$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me. The entire vs-code folder is empty!

I searched the recycle bin, vs-code backup folders, recovery tools for deleted files but found nothing.

Thanks to the message below, I found a copy of the code in the folder:
%appdata%/Code/User/History

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).